# Java - String of bytes to bytes[]

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have a

```
String b = "[B@64964f8e";
```

this is the byte[] output which i store in a string

Now I would like to convert it back to byte[]

```
byte[] c = b.getBytes();
```

but it gave me different byte which is

```
[B@9615a1f
```

how can I get back the same as [B@64964f8e ?

Comment: :) Read up on what the `toString()` method is.

Comment: In particular, the `"[B@64964f8e"` string is almost certainly of no actual value to start with.

Comment: How did you store the bytes in the string for the first time. Please add that code for better understanding

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with some sample input and expected output to clarify? I think there a many ways your question can be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> String b = "[B@64964f8e";
> ```

that's not a real string. That's the type and address of your byte array. It's nothing more than a transient reference code, and if the original array was GC'd you wouldn't even have a hope of getting it back with really funky native methods romping through memory.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to do the wrong thing and this won't help you at all because I would have though you want the contents to be the same, not the result of the toString() method.

You shouldn't be using a text String to binary data but you can use `ISO-8859-1`

```
byte[] bytes = random bytes
String text = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
byte[] bytes2 = text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); // gets back the same bytes.
```

But to answer your question, you can do this.

```
Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
unsafe.putInt(bytes, 1L, 0x64964f8e);
System.out.println(bytes);
```

prints

```
[B@64964f8e
```

Answer (score 1):

`"[B@64964f8e"` is not a string encoding of your `byte[]`. That is the result of the default `toString()` implementation, which tells you the type and reference location. Maybe you wanted to use base64-encoding instead, e.g. using [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`'s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) [`parseBase64Binary()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29) and [`printBase64Binary()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte%5b%5d%29):

```
byte[] myByteArray = // something
String myString = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myByteArray);
byte[] decoded = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(myString);
// myByteArray and decoded have the same contents!
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is:

`System.out.println(c)` prints the reference's representation of c object. **Not** c's content.*(Only in cases where Object's `toString()` method is not overriden)*

```
    String b = "[B@64964f8e";
    byte[] c = b.getBytes();

    System.out.println(c);             //prints reference's representation of c
    System.out.println(new String(c)); //prints [B@64964f8e
```